# How to return specific list result from linq to entities

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, lambda, linq-to-entities

Hi Experts
I currenly write this code:

```
public IList<TResult> GetCustomQuery<TResult>(int orderID, Func<Order, TResult> selector) 
    {
        using(RepositoryDataContext = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            IList<TResult> res = (from od in RepositoryDataContext.Order_Details
                                  join o in RepositoryDataContext.Orders
                                      on od.OrderID equals o.OrderID
                                  join p in RepositoryDataContext.Products
                                      on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID
                                  join c in RepositoryDataContext.Customers
                                      on o.CustomerID equals c.CustomerID
                                  where o.OrderID > orderID
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      o.OrderID,
                                      od.UnitPrice,
                                      od.Quantity,
                                      p.ProductName,
                                      c.CompanyName
                                  }).Select<Order, TResult>(selector).ToList();
        }
    }
```

I want to return result of my linq to entities in specific format(TResult).
writing this code using Lambda Expression is hard because of joins.
this line has exception :**Select < Order, TResult > (selector)**
how I can Fix that?
thanks

Comment: And what exception do you receive?

Comment: `cannot convert from 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<RepositoryWithEntityFramework.Order>'` and `System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,TResult>>)' has some invalid arguments`

Comment: 'Select new { }' statement will return an anonoymous type which could not be casted to any other type, neither it could be returned from the method.

Comment: thanks @Jose but How I can do that?can you show me an alternate way?

Comment: You can keep the return type of the method to be dynamic if you are working in c# 4.0. But Won't be generic.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating an Anonymous type, create a POCO or in your case an Order

```
select new Order()
{
 OrderProperty1 = o.OrderID,
 OrderProperty2 = od.UnitPrice,
 OrderProperty3 = od.Quantity,
 OrderProperty4 = p.ProductName,
 OrderProperty5 = c.CompanyName
}).Select<Order, TResult>(selector).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks.but it is not as simple as what u said.for using "Order()" Order class must be generic.If not it will throw to exception that like this : can not use Order because it have not new() constraint...

Answer (score 0):

In your second last line: Try to call ToList() before the Select(). Like this:

```
}).ToList().Select<Order, TResult>(selector);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible Iterate "res" and return a list of TResult?